# Using transaction.atomic to roll back recursive form validation + save

Tags: python, django, recursion

I want to validate and save a json "tree" recursively (`process_response` function below). If if any leaves in the tree are invalid, I want to roll back all the saved leaves so far. Here's an example of my approach:

```
@staticmethod
def process_response(post_data):
    """ brief pseudocode function to illustrate resursive form.save() """
    if is_leaf is True:
        if not form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponse(status=400)
        else:
            form.save(post_data)
            return HttpResponse(status=200)
    else: # is not a leaf, so must be a branch
        for child_data in post_data.children
            result = MyClass.process_response(child_data)
            if result.status_code != 200:
                return result

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    post_data = process_post_data(request) # json decoding, validation, etc
    with transaction.atomic():
        try:
            result = MyClass.process_response(post_data)
            if result.status_code != 200:
                raise DatabaseError
        except:
            return result
    return result
```

Will wrapping the call to the `process_response` function in `transaction.atomic` and raising a `DatabaseError` if any leaves don't validate allow me to do this?  Or is there another better way of validating and saving data in a "tree" structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you're calling `form.save()` for each leaf seems strange: normally you'd validate the whole thing once (recursively or not), and then save it once. The idiomatic approach would be to use the `validate()` and `save()` methods on a custom form class in conjunction with a [standard `POST` view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/#the-view).

That said, I'll assume you really do need some kind of recursive database save. In that case:

- The `try` clause [should surround](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic) the `atomic()` transaction.
- Leave `DatabaseError` to the database. Use something more appropriate, like `ValueError` or `ValidationError`.
- Leave the `HttpResponse` to the calling function, there's no reason to mix concerns like that into the recursive function.

My pseudocode would look something like:

```
def validate_and _save(data):
    if is_leaf:
        if not valid:
            raise ValueError()
        else:
            save_leaf()
    else:
        for child in children:
            validate_and _save(child)

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    post_data = process_post_data(request)

    try:
        with transaction.atomic():
            validate_and_save(post_data)
    except ValueError:
        return HttpResponse(status=400)
    else:
        return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

Comment: Does transaction.atomic roll back if the exception thrown isn't a `DatabaseError` or its subclass? With regard to validating first and saving second, I don't actually know how big the tree is in advance (just that it's one branch deep, in my case, but I don't know how many branches), so I'd have to record the tree structure while validating. Additionally, not all leaves are the same `model` type. I think recursive saving is more readable under those circumstances.

Comment: Eg, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/transactions/#controlling-transactions-explicitly see section on avoiding catching exceptions inside `atomic()`: The examples use `DatabaseError` subclasses

Comment: @Escher: Yes, the transaction is rolled back on any exception.